# Django pipeline doesn't load assets

Tags: python, django, django-pipeline

I've followed [this tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/) to make a sample project. The structure of the files is:

```
- mysite
    - mysite
         - __init__.py
         - settings.py
         - urls.py
         - wsgi.py
    - polls
         - migrations
         - templates
             - polls.html
         - static
             - script.js
             - style.css
         - admin.py
         - models.py
         - tests.py
         - urls.py
         - views.py
    - manage.py
```

Everything works well, but, the problem is using of [Django-pipeline](https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for managing the assets. I've configured my project as same as below codes, but it doesn't load assets properly.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    .
    .
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pipeline',
    'polls',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files')
PIPELINE_ENABLED = True
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'
PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.cssmin.CSSMinCompressor'
PIPELINE_CSSMIN_BINARY = 'cssmin'
PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.slimit.SlimItCompressor'

PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'pollsX': {
        'source_filenames': (
          'style.css',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'styles1.css',
        'variant': 'datauri',
    },
}
PIPELINE_JS = {
    'pollsX': {
        'source_filenames': (
          'script.js',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'scripts1.js',
    }
}
```

**polls.html**

```
{% load compressed %}
{% compressed_css 'pollsX' %}

<div class='red-me'>
    <h1> Hi! I'm a templ! </h1>
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
.red-me {
    color: red;
}
```

The generated output for `http://127.0.0.1/polls` is

```
<link href="/static/styles1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class='red-me'>
    <h1> Hi! I'm a templ! </h1>
</div>
```

It can not load `/static/styles1.css` file in the browser. Even, I tested `./manage.py collectstatic` without any success. Did I miss something?

*Python-3.4 and Django-1.7*

Comment: Hi! After you ran the `colletstatic` did the `styles1.css` is generated? Any update from the problem?

Comment: Yes, it it. The problem is in mode `DEBUG=False`. It doesn't load `styles1.css` from collected static files.

Answer (score 2):

Django pipline updates very frequently, so your particular tutorials are outdated already.
But I want to answer on your question anyway, because I just spent couple hours in fixing the same issue with new pipeline, and want to share my solution and hope it will be helpful for someone.

Everything works for:

- Django==1.9.1
- django-pipeline==1.6.4

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    .
    .
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pipeline',
    'polls',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'

PIPELINE = {
    'CSS_COMPRESSOR': 'pipeline.compressors.cssmin.CSSMinCompressor',
    'CSSMIN_BINARY': 'cssmin',
    'JS_COMPRESSOR': 'pipeline.compressors.slimit.SlimItCompressor',
    'STYLESHEETS': {
        'pollsX': {
            'source_filenames': (
                'style.css',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'css/styles1.css',
            'variant': 'datauri',
        },
    },
    'JAVASCRIPT': {
        'pollsX': {
            'source_filenames': (
                'script.js',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'js/scripts1.js',
        },
    }
}
```

**polls.html**

```
{% load pipeline %}
{% stylesheet 'pollsX' %}
{% javascript 'pollsX' %}

<div class='red-me'>
    <h1> Hi! I'm a templ! </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you misspelled your css file name.
Instead of using:

```
<link href="/static/styles1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Use:

```
<link href="/static/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: he does not need to specify his compressed file names, will be done automatically by {% load pipeline %} and {% javascript 'homejs' %} when PIPELINE_ENABLED = True

Comment: I was referring to a potential typo. Unrelated to compression file names.